# How to collapse multiple objects and toggle another one

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm currently at the beggining of the learning of JS and I was wondering how could I make one or more sections collapse when a button is clicked but still open the wanted section with `toggleSection()`
here is the whole script:

```
<body>
      <section id="features" class="none">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="single-item">
              <div><h3 class="kat_slick"><button type="button"onclick="toggleSection('kat')"> <img src="0full.jpg" alt=""> Katarina</button></h3></div>
                <div><h3 class="mercenarykat_slick"><button type="button"onclick="toggleSection('mercenary')"> <img src="1full.jpg" alt="">Katarina Mercenaire</button></h3></div>
                <div><h3 class="redcardkat_slick"><button type="button"onclick="toggleSection('redcard')"> <img src="2full.jpg" alt="">Katarina Carton Rouge</button></h3></div>
                <div><h3 class="bilgewaterkat_slick"><button type="button"onclick="toggleSection('bilgewater') "> <img src="3full.jpg" alt="">Katarina de Bilgewater</button></h3></div>
                <div><h3 class="kittykat_slick"><button type="button"class="blyat" onclick="toggleSection('kittykat')"> <img src="4full.jpg" alt="">Katarina Mistigri</button></h3></div>
                <div><h3 class="highcommandkat_slick"><button type="button"onclick="toggleSection('highcommand')"> <img src="5full.jpg" alt="">Katarina du Haut Commandement</button></h3></div>
                <div><h3 class="sandstormkatkat_slick"><button type="button"onclick="toggleSection('sandstorm')"> <img src="6full.jpg" alt="">Katarinadu Désert</button></h3></div>
                <div><h3 class="slaybellekat_slick"><button type="button"onclick="toggleSection('slaybelle')"> <img src="7full.jpg" alt="">Katarinadu Sucre d'Orge</button></h3></div>
                <div><h3 class="warringkingdomkat_slick"><button type="button"onclick="toggleSection('warringkingdom')"> <img src="8full.jpg" alt="">Katarinadu du Royaume en Guerre</button></h3></div>
                <div><h3 class="projectkat_slick"><button type="button"onclick="toggleSection('project')"> <img src="9full.jpg" alt="">Project : Katarina</button></h3></div>
                <div><h3 class="deathswormkat_slick"><button type="button"onclick="toggleSection('deathsworm')"> <img src="10full.jpg" alt="">Katarina Tanatophore</button></h3></div>
                <div><h3 class="battleacademiakat_slick"><button type="button"onclick="toggleSection('battleacademia')"> <img src="11full.jpg" alt="">Katarina de l'Académie de Combat</button></h3></div>
                <div><h3 class="bloodmoonkat_slick"><button type="button"onclick="toggleSection('bloodmoon')"> <img src="12full.jpg" alt="">Katarina Lune de Sang</button></h3></div>
                <div><h3 class="battlequeenkat_slick"><button type="button"onclick="toggleSection('battlequeen')"> <img src="13full.jpg" alt="">Katarina Reine du Combat</button></h3></div>
                <div><h3 class="highnoonkat_slick"><button type="button"onclick="toggleSection('highnoon')"> <img src="14full.jpg" alt="">Katarina de l'Ouest</button></h3></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>  
        </section>
        <section id="kat" style="display:none;"> <img src="0full.jpg" alt="">  </section>
        <section id="mercenary" style="display:none;"> <img src="1full.jpg" alt="">  </section>
        <section id="redcard" style="display:none;"> <img src="2full.jpg" alt="">  </section>
        <section id="bilgewater" style="display:none;"> <img src="3full.jpg" alt="">  </section>
        <section id="kittykat" style="display:none;"> <img src="4full.jpg" alt="">  </section>
        <section id="highcommand" style="display:none;"> <img src="5full.jpg" alt="">  </section>
        <section id="sandstorm" style="display:none;"> <img src="6full.jpg" alt="">  </section>
        <section id="slaybelle" style="display:none;"> <img src="7full.jpg" alt="">  </section>
        <section id="warringkingdom" style="display:none;"> <img src="8full.jpg" alt="">  </section>
        <section id="project" style="display:none;"> <img src="9full.jpg" alt="">  </section>
        <section id="deathsworm" style="display:none;"> <img src="10full.jpg" alt="">  </section>
        <section id="battleacademia" style="display:none;"> <img src="11full.jpg" alt="">  </section>
        <section id="bloodmoon" style="display:none;"> <img src="12full.jpg" alt="">  </section>
        <section id="battlequeen" style="display:none;"> <img src="13full.jpg" alt="">  </section>
        <section id="highnoon" style="display:none;"> <img src="14full.jpg" alt="">  </section>
```

and here are the function I use or tried to use:

```
<script>function toggleSection(id) {
        let section = document.getElementById(id);
        let display = section.style.display;
      
        if (display === "none") {
          section.style.display = "block";
        } else {
          section.style.display = "none";
        }
      }  
      jQuery('button').click( function(e) {
      jQuery('.collapse').collapse('hide');
      });
      </script>
```

My idea would be to link the first button for example to the first section,(which is easily doable with one function) but also to close all the other section if they are opened.

I tried to write a function where I was checking if their 'display' was 'none' and if they weren't, it would change it to none but it seemed that it was also closing the one I want to open at the first place.
I also tried to use Boootstrap but I just can't understand it by myself so it ended up not doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

I usually implement something like this by *first* hiding / collapsing *all* sections and *after* that show / expand the one with `id`. This way you don't have to trigger all the others individually.

So just put the `collapse('hide')` part at the top of your function.

```js
function toggleSection(id) {
    let section = document.getElementById(id);
    let display = section.style.display;

    // Give collapsible sections the `collapse` class.
    jQuery('section.collapse').collapse('hide');
  
    if (display === "none") {
      section.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      section.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Just give collapsible sections the `collapse` class (they don't have it in your HTML example).
You don't have to programmatically `click` all buttons this way.